# How to solve Nokia Lumia 520 windows 8.1 system busy for every call

Tags: lumia-520

I have Nokia lumia 520 and windows 8.1 for a while now. Suddenly I began to experience difficulties in browsing and I thought it was the network but now every time i want to make a call, when I launch the call either it does not ring or it says system busy.

Please how to solve that ? I called my provider and they said I have to check my phone, that the problem is with my phone.

Comment: have you tried resetting your phone at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to go to phone setting, click on about and then click on reset phone